# Windows 7 installation issues

Tags: windows-7, installation

I used to have an illegal Windows 7 on my computer, and as Ii got tired of the constant popups (not activated resolve online) I bought a legal issue and formated my computer.

Now every time I try to install it (both the 32 and 64  bit) it goes to about 2 or 3% of extracting files and then it stops with the message "windows 7 is unable to install, files are corrupt or missing"

So fix this and install Windows 7?

Comment: Since you now have a legal copy, call Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing out your dvd cd rom. I have this problem alot on systems that have an older dvd rom in it.

Answer (score 1):

start from scratch !

flash the system after formatting, make sure you have the proper setup disk [ not the build ] 
and insert disk

if this fails, then you might have a hardware problem:

1. check your cd/dvd player
2. check harddrive.
3. check memory.

Comment: Auch! This formatting hurts my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a legal serial number, download a Windows 7 installation disk from internet, the same as you version (home, ultimate...) - but be careful to do not download modified one. Burn the new disk and retry.